# Excel VBA: Producing all combinations of a range of values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I started off over at the math stack exchange to confirm some numbers first (which you'll see later), and now I'm here to try and get some guidance on how to accomplish a (hopefully simple) task in VBA.

Long story short: I have a range A1:A30 with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4...30. My program currently brings these values into an array, shuffles the array, and then "matches" a[0] with a[1], a[2] with a[3], a[4] with a[5], and so on down the line until each value is paired off. This results in, obviously, 15 matches total.

I've attached a screenshot showing the results on a separate sheet of 21 runs of the program. The trick here is that my code also makes sure that in the leftmost column, all the ID's only have a unique match within their respective row. No duplicates exist. If you follow row 5, you'll see that each value appears only once. You'll also see I've circled in red the matches for a particular run of the program (each column).

The problem is, that my shuffle works great, but 30 numbers means that there are 30 Factorial different possible results of that shuffle. However, it will only require me 29 runs of the program before every number has matched with every other number.

In total, there are 435 possible outcomes of 30 Choose 2. I'd like to produce a sheet similar to my screenshot, outlining all possible 435 outcomes. In other words, I'd like all possible outcomes for any number of n Choose 2.

My question: is there an elegant/concise way to set up some kind of loop to produce all 435 options.

I realize the question may not be 100% clear, so if you require clarification please let me know.

[image: Screenshot of the worksheet!]

Comment: Appreciate the edit suggestions!

Comment: I am just gonna comprehend this line by line: "This results in, obviously, 15 matches total." Unfortunately, not obvious to me. What matches with what?

Comment: Also so us some code. That would be much better than any explanation (if your code is written following some standards)

Comment: A double loop would easily create all the possible pairs, but I can't get my head round how that would relate to your screenshot. It would just be 435 rows (or columns) of data, each with two data items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have numbers 1-30 in range A1:A30, this code produces a string of all combinations and prints it to the immediate window. If you need to do math with the numbers instead of concatenating into a string, you just need to change the logic within the loop from adding to a string to performing your operation.

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim str As String

x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a30")

For i = LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        If str <> "" Then
            str = str & "," & x(i, LBound(x, 2)) & x(j, LBound(x, 2))
        Else
            str = x(i, LBound(x, 2)) & x(j, LBound(x, 2))
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

Comment: Error: Wrong Number of dimensions. And what's "y"?

Comment: Sorry, `y` was another array for a different approach I though of taking.

Comment: The else is so you don't end up with an errant comma on the first run through.

Comment: Also, not sure why you have an error. This run perfectly on my machine.

Comment: Just a preference: I would set str to something like "MyCombinations" and get rid of `Else` so it would be simplified. As I said preference, not even a suggestion.

Comment: What data type would `MyCombinations` be? The else isn't that complex. I was trying to put together a quick example to show the OP how to produce the combinations. The OP can do a little work to adjust tho their needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and comments! I'll definitely take a look at this today and test it out on my end. Obviously I can manipulate the range and loop to satisfy my dynamic criteria, but was having trouble with the beginning point. I also found some code over the weekend that worked perfectly, so I'll review that, compare to yours and between the two I'm sure I'll get things sorted out. Again, thanks very much!

Comment: Happy to help. Always feel free to post back clarifying questions too!

Comment: I found the first 3 "paragraphs of code" here: https://excel.tips.net/T006766_Listing_Combinations.html worked perfectly, before seeing your solution. Figured I'd let you know so you can see an alternative method. Now I will put my head back down and figure out how to get what I want.